# Show that if $X$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then: if $Y$ is bounded and $X \subset Y$, it follows that $\text{diam}\ X \leq \text{diam}\ Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**My attempt**

Let

- $X$ is bounded $\implies \exists x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } x_1 < x < x_2, \forall x \in X$
- $Y$ is bounded $\implies \exists y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } y_1 < y < y_2, \forall y \in Y$
- $X \subset Y \implies \forall x \in X, x \in Y$

$$ \text{diam} X = \sup\{|x - x_0| \ ;\ x, x_0 \in X\} $$

$$ \text{diam} Y = \sup\{|y - y_0| \ ; \ y, y_0 \in Y\} $$

We have by definition that the supremum is the least upper bound. In a definition of diameter, it is used to return the largest possible value. According to this fact, we have that the values that $\text{diam} X$ can assume are in the interval given by:

$$ 0 \leq \text{diam } X \leq |x_2 - x_1| $$

When the interval of values that diam $Y$ can assume is given by:

$$ 0 \leq \text{diam } Y \leq |y_2 - y_1| $$

Since $X \subset Y$, we can assume that:

$$ 0 \leq |x_2 - x_1 | \leq |y_2 - y_1| \implies \text{diam } X \leq \text{diam } Y $$

$$ \therefore \text{diam } X \leq \text{diam }Y $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem $1$**: Let $\emptyset \neq A\subset B \subset \mathbb{R},$ and $B$ is bounded (and so $\sup B$ and $\sup A$ both exist). Then, $\sup A \leq \sup B.$

*Proof*: Let $x<r:=\sup A,$ which by definition is the least upper bound of $A,$ and so $x$ is not an upper bound of $A.$ So there is $j\in A$ with $j>x.$ But $A \subset B,$ and so $j\in B$ also. Since $j$ is both $>x$ and a member of $B,$ it follows that $x$ is not an upper bound of $B.$ This shows that if $x< r,$ then $x$ is not an upper bound of $B,$ and therefore cannot be the supremum of $B.$ This implies $r \leq \sup B,$ i.e. $\sup A \leq \sup B.$

**Theorem $2$**: Let $T$ be any non-empty set, and suppose $f:T\to\mathbb{R} $ is bounded. If $\emptyset \neq S\subset T,$ then $\sup \{ f(s): s\in S \} \leq \sup\{ f(t):t\in T\}.$

*Proof*: It is easy to show that $\emptyset \neq \{ f(s): s\in S \} \subset \{ f(t):t\in T\}\subset\mathbb{R},$ and we already have from the question that $f:T\to\mathbb{R} $ is bounded, which implies that $\{ f(t):t\in T\}$ is bounded. Then the result follows from Theorem $1,$ by setting $B=\{ f(t):t\in T\}.$

Now for OP's question, use Theorem $2$ and put $T= Y\times Y,\ S= X\times X, $ and $f( (y_1,y_2)) = \vert y_1 - y_2\vert.$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not very clear. Supremum is not necessary a maximum, so what are these $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ that you used here?

Let $x_1, x_2\in X$ be any elements of $X$. Then they are also elements of $Y$, and hence $|x_1-x_2|\leq\text{diam}(Y)$. Since this is true for any $x_1,x_2\in X$, we see that $\text{diam}(Y)$ is an upper bound of the set $\{|x_1-x_2|: x_1, x_2\in X\}.$ But $\text{diam}(X)$ is by definition the least upper bound of this set, thus $\text{diam}(X)\leq\text{diam}(Y)$ as desired.